# ldap get objectguid (php ldap) with ldap_search

Tags: php, ldap, guid

I've an Application whith searches our ldap and saves a few attributes in a cache.
It's no problem to get attributes like mail displayname sn etc. but I dont get the objectguid.
Maybe its just a display error course the object id is in oktett or binary format. But i dont know exaktly if Im only not able to show the objectguid or if ldap doesnt give me the objectguid.

my code is

```
  $filter="(&(!(pager=))(!(pager=NO_MA)))";
  $justthese = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail", "pager","objectGUID");            
  $sr=ldap_search($ad, $basedn, $filter, $justthese);            
  $info = ldap_get_entries($ad, $sr);
```

i've tried different filters and without justthese i get always the same value in $myarray[$number][objectguid][0]. It is always NULL. 
A few trys after i got an output but with ldap_first_entry. but i want to get the value like all other values!
ive allready tryed to convert the guid with bin2hex() and unpack("H*hex,$guid") <- tryed different  methodes, but i got the same value (NULL).
btw i build my array like this:

```
 for ($i=0; $i<count($info); $i++) 
  {
      $myarray['ldap'][$i]["name"]      = utf8_decode($info[$i]["givenname"][0]);
      $myarray['ldap'][$i]["sname"]             = utf8_decode($info[$i]["sn"][0]);
      $myarray['ldap'][$i]["mail"]           = $info[$i]["mail"][0];
      $myarray['ldap'][$i]["pnr"]            = $info[$i]["pager"][0];

      $myarray['ldap'][$i]["guid"]           = $info[$i]["objectGUID"][0];
   }
```

did anyone have a idea to fix my problem?
or know a better way to read the complete ad ( with filters  and OBJECTGUID ) into an array?

thank you verry mutch if you answer...

Comment: What is desired by the the illegal assertion `(pager=)`? Perhaps the developer meant the negated present filter `(!(pager=*))`?

Comment: sorry this is my fault, i've editet so mutch. it should be pager not empty (pager=*). but this isnt the problem

Comment: omg.... now i've checked print_r($info) and what does i see?! a value in object id [0] => ��M⣽�I���%0�d�.

now i've to save this in valid format, and bin2hex(); is working. so this problem is solved! thank you all

Answer (score 2):

try this

`$myarray['ldap'][$i]["guid"] = mssql_guid_string($info[$i]["objectGUID"][0]);`

more info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-guid-string.php

Answer (score 0):

ObjectGUID must be lowercase like "objectguid"

```
$objectguid = bin2hex($entries['objectguid'][0]);
echo "Object Guid: ". $objectguid;
```

Result:

```
Object Guid: 362b6d25af3c9a42a23235e2c6c5e380
```